# bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect doesn't match SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit

I have in my scene playing board (for Tetris) - smaller then scene (750x510px). I need to frame it with bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect. Here is a code :

```
SKSpriteNode *herniPlocha = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"Plocha"];
herniPlocha.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
herniPlocha.position = CGPointMake(10, self.size.height-450);
herniPlocha.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:herniPlocha.frame];
[self addChild:herniPlocha];
```

but when I try to put block inside this board, the physicsBody doesn't match my board, it is about 40px moved to the right and up. Can you help me solve this problem, please?

Comment: the problem is seems to be because of your [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:herniPlocha.frame]; try to change width and height of herniPlocha.frame

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the anchorPoint. The anchorPoint shifts the texture relative to the node's position and does nothing else. It certainly does not change where the physics shape is relative to the node.

Comment: I tried to comment out anchorPoint and reposition it manually from middle point, but still when I add tetris block and try with gravity, still it is not matching picture of board, I will position my body manually. But thanks for answer.